# GDB debugger hangs on Fortran 90 READ command when reading from a text file

Tags: fortran, gdb, gfortran

I compile the fortran files into an executable (sei.exe) using the following command.

```
gfortran -g -fno-align-commons -c Creat2.for Bessel.for Kei.for
gfortran -g -fno-align-commons *.o D12e.for -o sei.exe
```

I then use gdb debugger by typing

```
gdb sei
```

Then I type the following to run it with the text file input

```
run < input.inp
```

It starts running but then just hangs.

I type Ctrl-C to interrupt it, and then it gives me the following result
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inwvt.png)

```
[New Thread 9052.0x42e4]
[New Thread 9052.0x32fc]
[New Thread 9052.0x5020]
[New Thread 9052.0x1d6c]
At line 408 of file Input.for (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: [New Thread 9052.0x5114]
End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
[Switching to Thread 9052.0x5114]
0x762b1985 in KERNELBASE!CtrlRoutine () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
```

Line 408 is where it is at when I interrupt it, which is the line

```
READ (*,20) TITLE
```

Here is the code surrounding that line

```
      DO 1665 I=1, MAXTIT
         READ (*,20) TITLE
         IF (LEN_TRIM(TITLE) .EQ. 0)GOTO 1664
         READ (TITLE,FMT=30,ERR=1664)DUMY1, DUMY2, DUMY3, DUMY4,
 1                                   DUMY5, DUMY6, DUMY7, DUMY8
```

Any ideas how to stop it hanging, and make it debug with the file input?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome, please enter the error message *as text*. That is really very important so that others can find your question if they have a similar problem. Do not use screenshots or if you do use them, always also supply the transcription. Just cut and paste the output.  If you do not know how to copy from a Windows terminal, use some tutorial like https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-windows-10-command-prompt-copy

Comment: I am not sure you can get much useful information from GDB here. The End of file error you got should be quite enough. You can of course go into the internal gfortran I/O routines and debug them, but that will be very hard to interpret. Rather, to actually solve your Fortran problem,  you should check whether the input file conforms to what the code expects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :) I have verified that, when i am not using gdb and I compile the code without the debug flag, the executable and input file work perfectly well together. The executable accepts the input file and runs perfectly producing the required output. It only doesn't work when i compile with the debug flag and use gdb.

Comment: In that case we will need a small [mcve] that does not work with GDB. Do not forget to tell us the exact versions of your operating ystem, of gdb, of the compiler and any other information like whether you use Cygwin, MinGW or any similar software distribution.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I will start working on producing that then. Thanks

Comment: I've remade the question here (don't know if i should've just edited this one..?) and tried to make a minimal reproducible example > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859014/gdb-debugger-hangs-on-fortran-read-command-when-reading-from-a-text-file

Comment: You could have edited this one but once you have a new question you can consider deleting the old one instead.