# GDB debugger hangs on Fortran READ command when reading from a text file

Tags: fortran, gdb, gfortran

This is my fortran code (fortcode.for)

```
        CHARACTER  TITLE*80                                                                                                                                         
        COMMON   IN                                                                                                        
        COMMON   TITLE 
        PARAMETER (MAXTIT=20)
  20    FORMAT (A80)    

  C*****FORTRAN LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER OF INPUT FILE                      
        IN  = 5                                  

        DO 1665 I=1, MAXTIT
          READ (IN,20) TITLE

  1665  CONTINUE

        CLOSE (IN)                        

        END
```

I compile the fortran file into an executable (fortexec.exe) using the following command.

```
gfortran -g -fno-align-commons fortcode.for -o fortexec.exe
```

I then use gdb debugger by typing

```
gdb fortexec
```

I then give it the following file input (input.inp)

```
  testx testy testz                    
  testx testy testz
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
  testk tety
```

By typing the following

```
run < input.inp
```

It starts running but then just hangs.

I type Ctrl-C to interrupt it, and then it gives me the following result

```
  [New Thread 10804.0x5b6c]
  [New Thread 10804.0x4974]
  [New Thread 10804.0x3c24]
  [New Thread 10804.0x4ae8]
  At line 11 of file fortcode.for (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
  Fortran runtime error: [New Thread 10804.0x48e8]
  End of file

  Error termination. Backtrace:

  Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
  [Switching to Thread 10804.0x48e8]
  0x765b1985 in KERNELBASE!CtrlRoutine () from 
  C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
```

Any ideas how to stop it hanging, and make it debug with the file input?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you probably did not give proper input file name, your setup ran no problem with gfortran on my laptop. if I give unexisting input it freezes and after CTRL+C I get the same warning.I would print what is read just to verify that it is working properly

Comment: So it ran fine when you used GDB debugger?

Comment: I think you are bit too quick here. This could be an issue  in the actual interplay of various versions of Windows, MinGW and GCC. As the  OP gave quite a bit of effort to diagnosed it (this is a follow-up of an older question) I would tend to believe the issue is real and may just be harder to reproduce. Generally, on StackOverflow, at least in the fortran tag, we tend to answer when we are reasonably certain what could be a problem, instead of just guessing.

Comment: I did not know that it is some kind of deeper test run. Yes, I did ran with GDB debugger, I am using:mingw-w64 x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0. I just copied the code and input data, ran on my laptop. I was mostly curios about GDB debugger. The code worked just fine, I added line below read line, to check how it is reading the data file. Since it did work, the only possibility from my view, was problem with input. I just deliberately mistyped the name of the file in the command and it did not give an error message on empty file or unexisting one. Just wanted to help when I had time.